# How do I fix 'ORA-00904: "Y": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"'?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am trying to create a SQL select statement that uses variable input in order to determine how the WHERE function operates. The code runs into unexpected problems.

I have tried to change the syntax of the conditions so that they use LIKE instead, but the problem still persists. The variable is definitely saved, but it still gives errors.

```
SELECT (SELECT description FROM froomtype rt 
       WHERE rt.roomtypeid = rsd.roomtypeid),
       SUM(totalrevenue)
FROM froomservicedata rsd
WHERE (SELECT requestdate FROM froomservice rs WHERE rs.roomserviceid = rsd.roomserviceid) >
    (CASE
         WHEN UPPER(&&timeperiod) = 'D' THEN 
             sysdate - interval '24' hour  
         WHEN UPPER(&&timeperiod) = 'W' THEN 
             sysdate - interval '7' day  
         WHEN UPPER(&&timeperiod) = 'M' THEN 
             sysdate - interval '1' month   
         WHEN UPPER(&&timeperiod) = 'Y' THEN 
             sysdate - interval '1' year
         ELSE
            sysdate + 1
    END)
GROUP BY (SELECT description FROM froomtype rt WHERE rt.roomtypeid = rsd.roomtypeid);
```

Here is the error message:

```
ORA-00904: "Y": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Comment: `&&timeperiod` is not a valid Oracle identifier AFAIK.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You can use this in sql developper and it will be replaced by the value you defined earlier :) 
Indeed if it is to be used in a stored procedure, it's not the proper syntax

Comment: An attempt to pass parameters?

Comment: @jarlh Yes, in Oracle SQL Developer you can pass variables to your queries by means of & (asks every time) or && (asks once and always uses it)

Comment: (Unrelated) tip.  `case UPPER(&&timeperiod) when 'D' then ... when 'W' then ... end` saves some typing.

Comment: Interesting, I will adjust my query. Thank you

Comment: Don't use `- INTERVAL '1' MONTH` as your query will fail when the date is 31st of the month and the previous month had less than 31 days in it. Instead use `ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 )` (or `ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -12 )` for years).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen To link to the documentation: `&` signifies a [substitution variable in SQL/Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a66736/ch33.htm) (and SQL Developer also supports the syntax). [`&&`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a66736/ch33.htm#1918) is a substitution variable that is only prompted for once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing single quotes.

Your query should be:

```
SELECT (SELECT description FROM froomtype rt 
       WHERE rt.roomtypeid = rsd.roomtypeid),
       SUM(totalrevenue)
FROM froomservicedata rsd
WHERE (SELECT requestdate FROM froomservice rs WHERE rs.roomserviceid = rsd.roomserviceid) >
    (CASE
         WHEN UPPER('&&timeperiod') = 'D' THEN 
             sysdate - interval '24' hour  
         WHEN UPPER('&&timeperiod') = 'W' THEN 
             sysdate - interval '7' day  
         WHEN UPPER('&&timeperiod') = 'M' THEN 
             sysdate - interval '1' month   
         WHEN UPPER('&&timeperiod') = 'Y' THEN 
             sysdate - interval '1' year
         ELSE
            sysdate + 1
    END)
GROUP BY (SELECT description FROM froomtype rt WHERE rt.roomtypeid = rsd.roomtypeid);
```

Cheers!!